# How to invoke the correct anaconda python in a script?

Tags: python, anaconda

When writing a python script, usually we put `#!/usr/bin/python` in the first line.

However I use python with ananconda. So I activate an environment and when I do `which python` I get

```
/home/mememe/miniconda3/envs/myenvironment/bin/python
```

As you can see this path is dependent on my user name `mememe` :) and the name of the environment `myenvironment`

What should I write so that I can invoke the correct python which is the one for the environment I created?

Answer (score 0):

This should work: substitute the first line with

with

```
#!/usr/bin/env /full/path/to/yourenv/bin/python
```

using the full path for the Python executable in your environment, so

```
#!/usr/bin/env /home/mememe/miniconda3/envs/myenvironment/bin/python
```